# Is there a homeostatic setpoint for number of hours of sleep required by a human?

Tags: human-biology, sleep, homeostasis

I've heard [this TED.com talk about dieting](http://www.ted.com/talks/sandra_aamodt_why_dieting_doesn_t_usually_work.html) and it mentions that there's a very definitive setpoint within the human brain about how much a human should weight. The speaker mentions that after as much as 7 years, the body returns to that [homeostatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_homeostasis#Sleep) weight setpoing.

I'm interested if there's something similar for sleep - **is there a homeostatic setpoint that says that a human should sleep X hours out of 24?**

In this example by homeostatic I mean:
If the sleep setpoint is at 9 hours, the human can sleep for 8 hours for some time, but when the artificial sleep restriction is removed, the human would return to 9 hours of sleep naturally.